# How to apply a scope on a Pivot model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue. Basically, I have a model "Affiliation" which has a one-to-many relationship with Candidates by the Pivot CandidateAffiliation. On the `belongsToMany`, I want to apply some scopes that will help me do some calculations later.

However, when I call the scope, I get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::paymentAvailable()`.

I feel like there is a way to do this, but I can't seem to make it work...

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Candidate extends Model
{
    public function affiliation() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Affiliation', 'candidate_invited_by');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Affiliation extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function candidates() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Candidate', 'candidate_invited_by');
    }

    public function hirees() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Candidate', 'affiliation_candidate')->withTimestamps()->using('App\AffiliationCandidate')->withPivot(['paid', 'cancelled']);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class AffiliationCandidate extends Pivot
{
    public function getStatusAttribute() {
        if($this->paid == true) {
            return 'payé';
        } elseif($this->cancelled == true) {
            return 'annulé';
        } elseif($this->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays(7)) {
            return 'en attente de paiement';
        } else {
            return 'en attente de validation (délai de 7 jours)';
        }
    }

    public function scopePaymentAvailable($query) {
        return $query->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
    }

    public function scopeNotPaid($query) {
        return $this->paymentAvailable()->where('paid', false);
    }

    public function scopePaid($query) {
        return $this->paymentAvailable()->where('paid', true);
    }
}
```

```
                <li>Nom complet: {{ $affiliation->user->candidate->full_name }}</li>
                <li>Email: {{ $affiliation->user->email }}</li>
                <li>Date d'inscription: {{ $affiliation->user->created_at->toDateString() }}</li>
                <li>Nombre de clics: {{ $affiliation->visits }}</li>
                <li>Nombre d'inscrit: {{ $affiliation->candidates()->count() }}</li>
                <li>Nombre d'embauchés: {{ $affiliation->hirees()->count() }}</li>
                <li>Montant total: {{ $affiliation->hirees()->paymentAvailable()->count() * 25 }}</li>
                <li>Montant disponible: {{ $affiliation->hirees()->notPaid()->count() * 25 }}</li>
                <li>Montant retiré: {{ $affiliation->hirees()->paid()->count() * 25 }}</li>
```

Comment: You can try to use in your belongsToMany relation `wherePivot`

Comment: @workservice Yeah, I just put everything in the Affiliation model with "wherePivot". Not really clean, but it's better than nothing! You can post as answer if you want.

Comment: Yeah i know it's not the cleanest way and it's repetitive mode, but since there isn't a workaround, this might be the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use in your `belongsToMany` relation `wherePivot()`